# Twitter Bootstrap Adjusting Widths - Landing Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking at creating a fairly simple Landing page using Twitter Bootstrap.  The landing page is in fairly basic straights at the moment however I have found that on my iPad and mobile phone it is not fully adjusting the widths of the different div's.

I'm not sure what I have not included or added to make the responsive CSS kick in? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://www.landing.xeonweb.com.au

Comment: Did you link the CSS files correctly?  It should be ready to go!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the error by adding in the CSS call in the Head Document media="screen"

So instead of:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have adjusted it too:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Was a silly mistake to not include the Media calls in the first place. Thanks!